How to get client's google business profile credentials to use google reviews API (without taking the actual credentials)
I am currently working with a restuarant with developing a website for online ordering and delivering.Client is requesting our team to show their google reviews in the website.When I searched it in google only possible way to use that API is google buisnees profile.
I want to know whether their is a way to use those google account details without seeing by our team members.Thank you.
